# Is it safe to send messages to Kafka when one of the brokers is down?

Tags: apache-kafka

My company has been running Kafka on a three-node cluster. Let us call the nodes node0, node1, node2.

All three nodes are running Kafka.

However, I found out I/O is screwed up in the mounting partition (`/mnt/`) on the node0 broker, and even the root cannot read, write, or execute any of the file there. It is strange how Kafka is still running.

The other two brokers are fine, but I think only one of them is actually functioning.

I want to replace the corrupted disk on node0, and then re-enable Kafka on it.

From my understanding, when I kill Kafka on node0, one of the other two, will elect itself as a leader, and it should work fine.

My concern is,

1. Keeping sending messages to master when Kafka is off might mess up node0 server. (I pass a comma separated list of all three brokers in the consumer, but I need to make sure it's safe)
2. The cluster might be poorly configured so that it's not a three-node cluster, but actually three one-node cluster, and it would not be fault-tolerant.

For example, on node1,

```
`$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic metric.topic`
`Topic:metric.topic PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: metric.topic Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1`
```

on node2,

`Topic:metric.topic    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs: Topic: metric.topic Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2`

(I cannot check this for node0, because of I/O permission is messed up there)

These two seem to run separately, although they receive the same messages from the producers.

How can I make sure these two things would not happen?

Especially, where in the Kafka documentation are they addressing my concern #1? (The Kafka documentation is preferable because I need to persuade engineers at my company that this is safe, because otherwise we will have to disable kafka producer for a day and we will lost any logs within that day.)

Answer (score 2):

Partitions of a topic have leader brokers that handle that partition. You can see that in your kafka-topics output where "Partition 0" has a leader of "Leader: 1".

You can see in your kafka-topics output that your intuition on #2 is correct. Those are two distinct topics, "node1" has a topic with a replica on broker ID 1 and "node2" has a topic with a replica on broker ID 2. This means that those two brokers are not part of the same cluster.

Passing multiple brokers to clients is preferred, and safe

So to answer your questions:

1)
Based on the output from kafka-topics it looks like "node0" and "node2" are in a cluster. That means you can bring down "node0" and "node2" will be elected the new leader. (I think node2 is the current leader based on "Leader: 2", although this depends on what ids you gave the brokers). When "node0" comes back up the data will be replicated to it until it is in sync and then it will be part of the ISR set.

> For a topic with replication factor N, we will tolerate up to N-1 server failures without losing any messages committed to the log. (From http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html)

To create a single cluster, make sure that the Zookeeper servers are configured to point to one another

```
server.1=your_zookeeper_node_1:2888:3888
server.2=your_zookeeper_node_2:2888:3888
server.3=your_zookeeper_node_3:2888:3888
```

And make sure each Kafka Broker uses all Zookeeper addresses for `zookeeper.connect`, rather than the default `localhost:2181`